# pitivi: project file incompatibility between release versions

Tags: configuration, flatpak, pitivi

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, and 've been using `pitivi` from the standard repo ... version 0.99-3.

I want to start using the `flatpak` version of `pitivi` with some rather complicated video projects of mine, but my existing project files are not compatible. The `flatpak` version I want to use is the one labeled "latest release" on this page ...
http://developer.pitivi.org/Install_with_flatpak.html?gi-language=undefined

My current Ubuntu version of `pitivi` creates project files with this header ...

```
<ges version='0.4'>
```

However, the latest `flatpak` version of `pitivi` seems to be older, and it produces project files with this header ...

```
<ges version='0.3'>
```

If I try to import my existing GES version 0.4 project files into the `flatpak` version of `pitivi`, I always get this error ...

> Unable to load project "Project1.xges"
>
> This might be due to a bug or an unsupported project file format. If
> you were trying to add a media file to your project, use the "Import"
> button instead.

I have tried changing all occurrences of "0.4" to "0.3" in my project files, but I still get the same error. There apparently have been syntax changes between 0.3 and 0.4 project file formats.

Does anyone know how to turn a GES 0.4 project file into one that is readable via GES 0.3? I don't want to have to re-create all these existing projects, just to be able to use the `flatpak` version of `pitivi`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the "1.0 Development Snapshot" at the same site that I mentioned above.

I had tried that Development Snapshot before, and it didn't work. But then, I uninstalled `pitivi` and `flatpak`, reinstalled `flatpak`, and then installed the `pitivi` `flatpak` distribution like this ...

```
$ flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
$ flatpak install flathub org.gnome.Platform//3.34
$ flatpak install http://flatpak.pitivi.org/pitivi.flatpakref
```

Then, my 0.4 project files started being readable.